# Асинхронная отправка Post запросов

Tags: c#, .net

Есть две копии одного класса.
В классе производится асинхронная отправка Post запросов (использую `webclient`).
В первой копии, отправка запросов и получение ответов производится без явных задержек.
Во второй копии, отправка и получении ответа может растягиваться на 5-10 секунд.
Все запросы отсылаются на один и тот же сайт, в обеих копиях.
Копии выполняются в разных потоках.

Никак не въеду, почему во второй копии класса отправка/получение `post` запросов настолько растягивается...
Прошу, объясните мне в чем проблема и как с ней бороться.

Спасибо.

Comment: Возможно это не ваш случай, но не так давно столкнулся с очень похожей проблемой: первый запрос занимает около 5-10 секунд (обычно 7), в то время как следующие выполняются почти мгновенно (запросы идентичные). Корень зла был в прокси (у меня она не использовалась и не упоминалась в коде), которую реализация вебклиента пытается проверить перед отправкой запросов (дефолтную). Проблема решилась простым присвоением нулл: 


webclient.Proxy = null;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Честно говоря, для хорошего ответа малова-то конкретики в вопросе, но давайте попробуем.

Теперь об узких местах:

1. Сам класс `webClient` - очень маловероятно. Каких-то особых приколов в нем нет (ну по крайней мере я не слышал).
2. Ваше сетевое оборудование (пропускная способность канала), либо какой-то фильтрующий прозрачный-прокси, фаервол-антивирус и т.п. - ну мало ли чего может быть.
3. Защита от перегруза (DoS'a) на конечном сервере. Наверно самая вероятная причина. Перед сервером стоит обратный прокси, типа `nginx`, и контролирует, чтоб по некотором запросам не было больше чем N запросов за Х секунд с одного или группы адресов. Попробуйте делать второй запрос с небольшой задержкой.

P.S. Запросы я так понимаю абсолютно одинаковы в обоих классах. Если запросы разные - то вопрос не имеет смысла - никто кроме авторов сайте не может знать, как работает тот или иной сервим и сколько времени ему нужно на обработку запроса - может и 5 секунд, может и 25)
Пробуйте экспериментировать с данными, которые вы даете серверу, может их можно совать меньшими частями... Может какие-то вещи можно делать на более быстром сервере. Может можно купить "премиум аккаунт", который будет такие вещи делать быстрее.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ :)
Уже разобрался - я напортачил с созданием потоков.